# Does Wily have inherently better WiFi performance than Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hardware, 15.10

I started with 15.04 on a Lenovo G70-80 and after a few days upgraded to 15.10. WiFi performance on 15.10 was noticeably better than it had been on 15.04. Then I downgraded to (installed afresh) 14.04 from 15.10 and noticed significant WiFi speed drop. To see if WiFi performance is really contingent on OS versions, I again upgraded to 15.04 and then to 15.10. I noticed speed increases as I upgrade.
Is it a fact regarding OS versions (and kernel coming with OS's)? Or is it my hardware? And I have a weak-to-fair WiFi signal because of router's distance from machine.
I had 64-bit GNOME flavor in all cases.

Comment: It's likely related to your hardware, because newer OS comes with newer kernel, and that comes with newer drivers (modules). It could also be software side, because 15.10 uses different init stystem (systemd) and different version of network-manager ( which shouldn't impact wifi performance that much, it's still the same wifi card, so I tend to think it's the kernel update )

Comment: That makes sense. I will try kernel update.

Answer (score 1):

The OS will not influence radio signal strength. But the firmware of the WiFi HW and its setup may do. With every Ubuntu you get firmware files (located in /lib/firmware). Depending on your WiFi HW one of these files may be loaded at startup. If you experience such an obvious difference, you should check the difference of the firmware file in question.

It may also depend on some configuration settings, especially the country setting is influencing the transmission power. Have a look at

```
iwconfig
```

and the Tx-Power value. Some WiFi HW has two or more antennas which can be configurated. But for these deeper details the type of HW needs to be known.

Last point is self made interference. For example the beaglebone black is known to interfere WiFi with its own HDMI output. So this shall be disabled for better WiFi results. Every PC may have components interfering its own WiFi. So WiFi performance depends on the operation state of these.

But NO Wily does not overall have a better WiFi performance than Trusty.